# converting int to date in python

Tags: python

i have the following column

```
day
20190101
20190101
20190102
20190103
```

I want to change it to `01-01-2019`.

I used the following code for that

`data['day'] =  pd.to_datetime(data['day'], format='%Y/%m/%d')`

but it gives the following output instead: `1970-01-01 00:00:00.020190101`

`data[["day"]] = data[["day"]].apply(pd.to_datetime)`

also tried

`data['day'] =  pd.to_datetime(data['day'], format='%Y/%m/%d')`

expected output is `01-01-2019` but the actual output is `1970-01-01 00:00:00.020190101`

Comment: It is weird output format, if use `data['day'] =  pd.to_datetime(data['day'])` or `data['day'] =  pd.to_datetime(data['day'], format='%Y%m%d')` not working?

Comment: nope not working

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply implement:

```
def func(val):
    x = str(val)
    return '{}-{}-{}'.format(x[6:8],x[4:6],x[0:4])
```

And then run it for each entry.

Answer (score 0):

Just fix the `format` argument of [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) function, you have `%Y/%m/%d` while the actual format is `%Y%m%d`:

```
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'], format='%Y%m%d')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
        day         dt
0  20190101 2019-01-01
1  20190101 2019-01-01
2  20190102 2019-01-02
3  20190103 2019-01-03
```

Comment: data['day'] = pd.to_datetime(data['day'], format='%Y%m%d')

data['day']

Comment: 1970-01-01 00:00:00.020190101
1      1970-01-01 00:00:00.020190101
2      1970-01-01 00:00:00.020190101
3      1970-01-01 00:00:00.020190101
4      1970-01-01 00:00:00.020190101
5      1970-01-01 00:00:00.020190101
6      1970-01-01 00:00:00.020190101
7      1970-01-01 00:00:00.020190101
8      1970-01-01 00:00:00.020190101
9      1970-01-01 00:00:00.020190101
10     1970-01-01 00:00:00.020190101
11     1970-01-01 00:00:00.020190101
12     1970-01-01 00:00:00.020190101
13     1970-01-01 00:00:00.020190101
14     1970-01-01 00:00:00.020190101

Comment: Can we see `data['day'].head().tolist()` please?

Comment: ['01-01-1970', '01-01-1970', '01-01-1970', '01-01-1970', '01-01-1970'] this

Comment: So you actually have values like 01-01-1970 in that column instead of 20190101

Comment: nope thats after i convert it to date time, before converting it shows [20190101, 20190101, 20190101, 20190101, 20190101]

Comment: I get the same problem as you if I run `pd.to_datetime(df['day'])` but it works perfectly fine with `pd.to_datetime(df['day'], format='%Y%m%d')`, just make sure you run it on the original dataset before you try converting it some other way